# Get notification while mobile is in IDLE state

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I got the notification on multiple mobiles from server only when all mobile's screen is in ON condition. But when I try to send notification when mobiles are in IDLE(OFF screen) mode, then notification sent from server successfully but not received by mobiles.

I tried with 12 to 15 mobiles, same issue happened all the time.
I am using FCM to send notification. I made my own server to send notification which uses FCM.

So, I want to receive notification in both modes while screen is ON or OFF.

Comment: you need to send the notification in Notification PayLoad as key/value pairs entered in Custom data are handled as a data payload for the notification. Other fields map directly to keys in the FCM notification payload.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you find a solution? Thanks. ps creating the notification with "data" payload doesn't help.